# show result of multi sql procedure and use it in view

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table that named 'place'

```
create table place( ID int , Name varchar)
```

i have a procedure that named 'placeshow' with one parameter
my end is show all result of procedure for table place rows
for example :

```
    exec placeshow @placeid=1
    exec placeshow @placeid=2
    exec placeshow @placeid=3
    exec placeshow @placeid=4
    .......
    .......
    exec placeshow @placeid=5
```

i need to run code like some this and show the result of that query
at the end i should save the result in a view
please help me

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like below,

```
 DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SELECT @Sql = (SELECT '
        ; 
        exec PlaceShow ' + CAST(ID aS VARCHAR(10))
     FROM Place 
     FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)')
INSERT INTO tbl_output --this is the table where you can insert your results and use however you want
    EXEC(@Sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you don't have control on them?... so you can use loop.. 
for example..**

DECLARE @resultTable TABLE(id int,col1 vrachar(10),col2 varchar(20))

declare @temp int

declare @temp1 int

WHILE @temp <= (select count(placeid) from Place)

BEGIN

Select @temp1 = placeid

From 
(

```
Select 
  Row_Number() Over (Order By placeid) As RowNum
, *
From TABLE
```

) t2

Where RowNum = placeid

if not exists(select 1 from Place where id=@temp1)

begin

INSERT INTO @resultTable

EXEC placeshow @placeid=@temp1

end

END;

Comment: hello but the value in place table is very diffrent

Comment: for example , some times just i have 3 records with id 100,60043,400334. with your code , sql should start from 1 to 400334 and count it

Comment: I have used that method but the result is Empty